# sequel select_all(:model) returns incorrect ruby object

Tags: ruby, sequel

I may missing something, but I couldn't find documentation for such case. I'm trying to fetch model generating big sql query, and then do some modification with those data. But returning model is not correct (ruby object associated with it) but data (columns) is correct. Consider the following example

```
Models::Offers
  .association_join(:companies)
  .where(companies__uin: params[:uin])
  .select_all(:companies)
  .to_a
#=> #<Models::Offer @values={:id=>111, :uin=>'xxx', :title => 'xxx', :state=>"xxx" ..>
```

All those columns/data belongs to `Models::Company` model and fetched correctly from database, but resolving as `Models::Offer` is incorrect, so ruby object generated is wrong and I cannot get why

Comment: This is expected because you start your query with `Models::Offers`. I am not familiar with the `sequel` gem but I with my knowledge about other ORMs would try to just change the query to something like `Models::Companies.association_join(:offers).where...` (naming, of course, depends on your models and database schema).

Comment: @spickermann yeah, I think you are right, but my question is it expected behaviour?
because for me it definitely should `Models::Company` as a result, or something else, but not `Models::Offer` with columns of companies table

Comment: Yes, this is expected. It always uses the model from which the query was built no matter what columns are returned. You can even return columns from multiple tables at the same time when the query includes a join. Or it can include attributes from virtual columns – like counts or sums.